# Delete DataFrame if condition is true - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sorry if this is obvious (I feels like it should be).  I am downloading stock data using a for loop to create a set of dataframes labeled with the ticker name. I wish to not download stocks that return less than x rows in the downloaded data.

I currently have this that is not working?

```
with open('Tickers/25_tickers.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

    for Symbol in lines:
        print(Symbol)
        vars()[Symbol] = pd.DataFrame()
        vars()[Symbol] = yf.download(Symbol, start, end, interval= '1d')
        i = vars()[Symbol].shape[0] #try to remove empty and low row df.
        if i > 10 == True:
                pass
```

When I use  `%whos DataFrame` I get the list of 'ticker' DataFrames and the problem DataFrames still exist.
I'm also not sure if I should do it while downloading or after the dataframes are in.
Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('Tickers/25_tickers.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

    for Symbol in lines:
        print(Symbol)
        vars()[Symbol] = pd.DataFrame()
        vars()[Symbol] = yf.download(Symbol, start, end, interval= '1d')
        i = vars()[Symbol].shape[0] #try to remove empty and low row df.
        if i < 10:
            del vars()[Symbol]
```

Comment: Yup that'll do it! Thanks Deven. Just realised I had to put the other functions above the 'if' to continue the loop.